# Filters on Login Page

Tags: filters, login, wp-login-form

I am trying to modify the login page using [built in filters](http://codex.wordpress.org/Customizing_the_Login_Form).  The add_actions are working as expected, but I cannot get the filters to work.  This is the code that I have in my functions.php:

```
add_filter( 'login_form_top', 'filter_top_login' );
function filter_top_login( $content )
{
    return 'This is what I want it to say!';
}
```

but it doesn't seem to be doing anything when I load the wp-login.php page.  What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3):

While `login_form_top` is a valid hook called by the [`wp_login_form`](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.5.1/wp-includes/general-template.php#L257) function, `wp_login_form` ***is not used*** in [`wp-login.php`](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.5.1/wp-login.php), nor is that function used anywhere else that I can find. I `grep`ed my entire 3.5.1 install and found one reference to the function-- *the place where it is defined*. It does not appear to actually be used anywhere by the Core.

You will need to search the `wp-login.php` file for hooks, such as [`login_form`](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.5.1/wp-login.php#L689), and try to do what you need with those hooks, or write your own login page (though it sounds like that is what you are trying to avoid).

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `login_message` filter, which will show your text just above the login form:

```
add_filter( 'login_message', 'my_login_message' );

function my_login_message() {
    return 'This is my message';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`login_form_top` filter isn't called in wp-login.php.

The only hook I can see in wp-login.php in login form area is `login_form` (it's called on line 689). But it's placed after both inputs (login/password) so it's more like `login_form_middle`.

Answer (score 0):

As it is mentioned that `login_form_top` filter is not available in 'wp-login.php', alternatively, we can try placing it somewhere else and move it with javascript.

For example, you can insert code in footer (using *login_footer*) and move it to required place using javascript.

```
add_action( 'login_footer', 'login_form_customization', 12 );
function login_form_customization() {
    ?>
    <p id='custom-login-html'>
        This is my html code.
    </p>
        
    <script>
        var htmlcode = document.getElementById("custom-login-html");
        var loginform = document.getElementById("loginform");
        loginform.prepend(htmlcode);
    </script>
<?php
}
?>
```

Answer (score -1):

just remove the $content variable,

```
    add_filter( 'login_form_top', 'filter_top_login' );
function filter_top_login()
{
    return 'This is what I want it to say!';
}
```

Comment: That makes no difference. As a couple of other people have noted, the `login_form_top` filter is not called on wp-login.php. The `login_message` filter can be used instead.

Comment: yes you are right. I think I havent read carefully, I used that filter in wp_login_form, but question is looking for wp-login.php.